# To what extent do 'earn income' and 'generate income' differ?

Tags: meaning, verbs, expressions

I've had a short search on this but may have overlooked an easily-accessible source that differentiates the two. They don't seem synonymous, but I can't yet point to a definition of the two.

To me, *earning income* relates to an individual or team working for a wage/salary, with the focus on the active, and *generating income* is via more passive means.

Is that correct? How would you define the two?

Comment: What dictionary difference of *earn* and *generate* are unclear to you?

Comment: Work generates income. The worker earns income.

Comment: I think the *literal* distinction between the two terms is General Reference, and the extent to which different speakers are prepared to use them interchangeably in *figurative* contexts is POB.

Comment: Your assumption as to the distinction is mostly correct (though "generate" doesn't strongly imply that the income is coming to you vs your employer or someone else).  The terms will have more precise meanings in tax and financial business contexts.

Comment: POB = place of birth? Are you referring to regional differences?

Answer (score 1):

I don't work for a profit-making enterprise, but if I did, I could say that while I am sitting here answering your question I am earning the salary the company pays me, but I am not generating any income for the company.  After I finish answering this question, I would go back to working on the project that, when complete, will generate income for the company.

I am a part-time author.  I have yet to earn a single cent for this work.  Once my book is published it will sell many copies, and those sales will generate a nice income.  At least that is my fond hope.

"Generate" in the context presented suggests something that is happening independently of your immediate labor is creating income.  "Earn" is something direct, received for your immediate labor.

HOWEVER, all that being said, "generating income" and "earning income" are near-synonyms.  They can be used interchangeably, but *can* also be used to distinguish between direct or indirect income sources.

Answer (score 0):

Earn just means earn ("payment for work").

Generate just means generate (ie "makes" -- just as in an electricity generator).

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a little different to activity and passivity.

To me, it's about the difference between the recipient of the income and the entity creating the income.

Income earners receive the income that they create. Generally, that limits earners to individuals and organizations.

Income generators create income that goes to other entities. As such, this can include individuals and organizations (I can generate income for my employer), but also advertisements (through referral fees), books & music (through royalties), property (through rent), etc.

Purely from the recipient's perspective, however, I suppose earning is active and generation is passive.

Answer (score -1):

In this context, "Earn Income" is what you get for your own efforts, i.e. through your job.  "Generate Income" is for more passive income, for example by investments that yield income.